# Why "Settings" needs Cellular in iOS?

Tags: ios, settings, cellular-data, data

I'm getting a similar warning as this one:

[image: Settings needs Cellular]

Whenever I get to Settings in iOS. I have deactivated Cellular connections for *everything* (including Settings) but Chrome Browser.

I'm wondering if anyone know why Settings needs a Cellular connection?

As seen on this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6567893

Answer (score 2):

Not to start a Greek chorus here but I checked on my iPhone 5 with the latest IOS (8.1.1) wth wifie and cellular data off and I do not get that message either.

I am thinking that possibly ajkblue is correct and it may be trying to contact Apple's software update servers or your carriers servers for a carrier update. there is likely a timer that forces a check every week or so.

The job of settings app is to use all possible connections to check for updates and it’s letting you know you explicitly disable it from using cellular data. You will likely miss security updates and not save any data by stopping these brief checks from using cellular connections.

In my case, settings used 80 KB of data this billing period and 210 KB last billing period.

Comment: It happens only for cellular data, of course. The prompt shows *every time* I go to Settings.